# array is not working in a function which is inside for loop of jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I am stuck at a point,its worpress mediauploader. I want to upload images, one function is for one image but I have several upload buttons with unique id so I want only one function for all thats why I created the loop, on click of each button media uploader open up but there is problem saving the selected image, I am not getting that image url in the value. pls help new to jquery and javascript. Tried various methods this is one of them
this is screenshot of thing that I want->[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zSHWm.png)

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
var b = ["#upload-button-1", "#upload-button-2", "#upload-button-3","#upload-button-4","#upload-button-5","#upload-button-6","#upload-button-7","#upload-button-8"];

var d =[".procircle-1", ".procircle-2",".procircle-3",".procircle-4",".procircle-5",".procircle-6",".procircle-7",".procircle-8"];
var j;
 var c = ["#grid-image-1", "#grid-image-2", "#grid-image-3","#grid-image-4","#grid-image-5","#grid-image-6","#grid-image-7","#grid-image-8"];
var i;

for(i=0; i<=b.length; i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<=c.length;j++){
        $(b[i]).on('click',function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            if( mediaUploader ){
            mediaUploader.open();
            return;
            }

            mediaUploader = wp.media.frames.file_frame= wp.media({

                title:'Choose a Picture for Procedure ',
                button:{
                    text:'Choose Picture'
                },
                 multiple:false                                                 
            });


            mediaUploader.on('select',function(){

                attachment= mediaUploader.state().get('selection').first().toJSON();
                $(c[j]).val(attachment.url);
                $('.procircle-2').css({'background':'url(' + attachment.url + ')','background-repeat': 'no-repeat'});

            });


        mediaUploader.open();

        });
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: damn class why an earth are you people not using it??

Comment: `I have several upload buttons with unique id so I want only one function for all` --> use classes..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest doing the following (if you must keep your ids etc):

```
$(document).on('click', '#upload-button-1, #upload-button-2, #upload-button-3, #upload-button-4, #upload-button-5, #upload-button-6, #upload-button-7, #upload-button-8', function(e) {
    var match = e.target.id.match(/(\d+)/g);
    e.preventDefault();
    if(mediaUploader) {
        mediaUploader.open();
        return;
    }

    mediaUploader = wp.media.frames.file_frame = wp.media({
        title:'Choose a Picture for Procedure ',
        button:{
            text:'Choose Picture'
        },
        multiple:false                                                 
    });

    mediaUploader.on('select', function(){
        var attachment = mediaUploader.state().get('selection').first().toJSON();
        var id = '#grid-image-' + match[1];
        $(id).val(attachment.url);
        $('.procircle-2').css({'background':'url(' + attachment.url + ')','background-repeat': 'no-repeat'});
    });

    mediaUploader.open();
});
```

This removes the loop and delegates your handler so you only create one click handler rather than one per loop iteration as you are currently, and also creates a single mediauploader select handler. Finally, match the corresponding input with the event target that performed the click. Should work, although you might need to play around with it a bit, and it could definitely be refactored to be nicer. Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for the effort but its not working , getting image in background but having problem with value 
mediaUploader.on('select', function(){
        var attachment = mediaUploader.state().get('selection').first().toJSON();
        var id = '#grid-image-' + match[1];
        $(id).val(attachment.url);
        $('.procircle-2').css({'background':'url(' + attachment.url + ')','background-repeat': 'no-repeat'});
    });

Comment: getting value as well but for the  first grid-image-1 even after choosing image for #upload-button-3 or so

Comment: Can you put a jsbin/fiddle example up? I can't really debug what's going on from a picture. You could also add a data attribute to your button that points to the id of your file input, and use that to target instead of running regex on the target id.

Comment: I fixed it , now its working but I have to save it before uploading 2 nd  pic